# Plotting a series of numbers into horizontal lines

Tags: charts, pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I've been trying to figure out the code to plot lines like these based on me copy and pasting a series of numbers into the code each day.  I was trying to use an array but I'm not sure that's what I need to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU5xh.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Input Levels", overlay = true)

lev1 = input.float(3990, title = "Val 1", inline = "1")
col1 = input.color(color.black, title = "", inline = "1")
lev2 = input.float(3890, title = "Val 2", inline = "2")
col2 = input.color(color.green, title = "", inline = "2")
lev3 = input.float(3995, title = "Val 3", inline = "3")
col3 = input.color(color.black, title = "", inline = "3")
lev4 = input.float(3870, title = "Val 4", inline = "4")
col4 = input.color(color.red, title = "", inline = "4")
lev5 = input.float(3826, title = "Val 5", inline = "5")
col5 = input.color(color.black, title = "", inline = "5")

var float[] level_vals = array.from(lev1, lev2, lev3, lev4, lev5)
var color[] color_vals = array.from(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)

var line[] level_lines = array.new_line()

size = array.size(level_vals)

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to size - 1
        array.push(level_lines, line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, style = line.style_dashed, color = color.black, extend = extend.both))

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to size - 1
        line_i = array.get(level_lines, i)
        val_i = array.get(level_vals, i)
        color_i = array.get(color_vals, i)
        line.set_xy1(line_i, x = bar_index - 1, y = val_i)
        line.set_xy2(line_i, x = bar_index, y = val_i)
        line.set_color(line_i, color = color_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the numbers in an array, then run a for loop in the array and plot dashed line at them. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Plot numbers")
var numbers=array.from(3992.5,3990.25,3989,3987.25,3985,3983.25,3981,3977.25,3971.25,3966.5)
if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to array.size(numbers) - 1
        line.new(bar_index, array.get(numbers,i),bar_index,  array.get(numbers,i), style = line.style_dashed, color = color.black, extend = extend.both)
```